# D2 as covering map

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose p is a covering map from  D^2  to X where X is a topological space and D^2 is the closed unit disk. Determine the space X up to homeomorphism.

I have read that since Euler characteristic of D2=1 this imply Euler char of X=1 therefore X~D2. How?

Answer (score 2):

Are there any non-trivial examples? Any example would be a quotient
of $D^2$ by a group acting freely on it, but any continuous map
from $D^2$ to itself has a fixed point.

Comment: I think that does it.